# How to automate control of Wemo light switch based on iPhone GPS

Tags: python, ios

I'm writing a program to toggle the lights at my house based on my iPhone's GPS coordinates. Below is what I have so far. However, I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Is there a way to get GPS data without pinging my phone every five minutes?

So far I've tried the following with no joy:

- Using Shortcuts and Scriptable I tried to write some JavaScript that would trigger when I got close to home. However, I could not figure out how to use `await require('wemo-client')` using [scriptablify](https://talk.automators.fm/t/tips-how-to-use-npm-modules-in-scriptable/5747). I kept getting an error, "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require".
- IFTTT does not have a variable timed trigger so the lights won't turn off after 15 minutes. Also, I plan on adding a motion sensor trigger that is unsupported.
- Pythonista is $10. Yes, I am that cheap.
- Apple HomeKit does not support the model I'm using, Wemo Smart Light Switch F7C030.
- The code below *works*, but I hate that I have to ping my phone every five minutes. I'd rather save battery life by firing this code once or twice a day, as needed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
import pywemo

APPLE_ID = os.getenv('APPLE_ID') # Apple ID username
APPLE_ID_PASSWORD = os.getenv('APPLE_ID_PASSWORD') # Apple ID password
API = PyiCloudService(APPLE_ID, APPLE_ID_PASSWORD)
IPHONE = API.devices[1]
LOCATION = IPHONE.location()
FIVE = 300 # 5 * 60 seconds
FIFTEEN = 900 # 15 * 60 seconds
ONEMILE = 0.01449275362318840579710144927536 # one mile is 1/69 degrees lat or long
HOMELAT = # my home's latitude
HOMELONG = # my home's longitude
WEMOS = pywemo.discover_devices()
LEN_WEMOS = range(len(WEMOS))

# Two factor authentication to retrieve iPhone data
if API.requires_2fa:
    import click
    print("Two-step authentication required. Your trusted devices are:")

    DEVICES = API.devices
    for i, device in enumerate(DEVICES):
        print("  %s: %s" % (i, device.get('deviceName', "SMS to %s" % device.get('phoneNumber'))))

    DEF_DEVICE = click.prompt('Which device would you like to use?', default=0)
    DEVICE = DEVICES[DEF_DEVICE]
    if not API.send_verification_code(DEVICE):
        print("Failed to send verification code")
        sys.exit(1)

    CODE = click.prompt('Please enter validation code')
    if not API.validate_verification_code(DEVICE, CODE):
        print("Failed to verify verification code")
        sys.exit(1)

# Turn off the lights when I leave
def leavehome():
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Left home on {}".format(timenow.strftime("%B %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S")))
    for wemo in LEN_WEMOS:
        WEMOS[wemo].off()

# Turn on the lights for 15 minutes when I get home
def arrivehome():
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Arrived home on {}".format(timenow.strftime("%B %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S")))

    # Loop through all Wemo devices
    for wemo in LEN_WEMOS:
        WEMOS[wemo].on()

    time.sleep(FIFTEEN)
    for wemo in LEN_WEMOS:
        WEMOS[wemo].off()

# Automatically turn off the lights after 15 minutes - save electricity
def timeoff():
    time.sleep(FIFTEEN)
    for wemo in LEN_WEMOS:
        WEMOS[wemo].off()

# Ping my phone for GPS data
def pingphone(prev):
    mylat = LOCATION["latitude"]
    mylong = LOCATION["longitude"]
    logic(prev, mylat, mylong)
    time.sleep(FIVE)

# Perform logic to determine if I'm home, out, arriving, or leaving
def logic(prev, lat, long):
    inrange = (HOMELAT+ONEMILE >= lat >= HOMELAT-ONEMILE and HOMELONG+ONEMILE >= long >= HOMELONG-ONEMILE)
    current = bool(inrange)
    previous = prev
    if current and not previous:
        arrivehome()
    elif previous and not current:
        leavehome()
    else:
        timeoff()

    pingphone(current)

# Run the script
pingphone(False)
```

Comment: Have you integrated your Wemo with Apple HomeKit?  If not then I suggest you do that. Then, not only will you get Siri control of your Wemo products but you can configure a shortcut in the Apple Shortcuts app to do what you want in about 30 seconds. You will need an iPad, Apple TV or HomePod on your home network to be able to control things when you aren’t connected to the local wifi network

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround. Unfortunately, Apple HomeKit does not support the model I'm working with (Wemo Smart Light Switch, F7C030).

Comment: It might be supported by homebridge https://github.com/rudders/homebridge-platform-wemo